# WM_ERASEBKGND event handler default implementation

Tags: c, winapi

Does anyone know what is the default implementation (source code) for the event handler of the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message?

Comment: Are you asking for MS source code?

Comment: @Weather Vane Yes, I'm wondering if the source code for the `DefWindowProc()` is available, or someone has disassemble it or something :-)

Comment: It is documented anywhere you could possible look.  It uses the WNDCLASSEX.hbrBackground you specified.

Answer (score 3):

It's basically something like this:

```
case WM_ERASEBKGND:
{
    HBRUSH hBsh = reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(GetClassLongPtr(hWnd, GCL_HBRBACKGROUND));
    if (!hBsh) return FALSE;

    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
    FillRect(reinterpret_cast<HDC>(wParam), &rc, hBsh);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: So the code does not validate the drawn area, that is up to `WM_PAINT` only? Also your code shows that the entire client area is drawn, however, my testings shows that only the invalidated area is drawn (use `InvalidateRect()` with a `RECT` that covers only a portion of the client area and you'll see that).

Comment: The DC passed to `WM_ERASEBKGND` is clipped to the invalidated region automatically. Validation is handled at the point the `WM_PAINT` / `WM_ERASEBKGND` messages are generated depending on the return value received (e.g. if `WM_ERASEBKGND` returns true, either because your window proc handled it or `DefWindowProc` handles it, the region is then validated). Remember, Windows doesn't "know" if you called `DefWindowProc` from your window proc or handled it yourself, all it sees is the return code.

Comment: Based on my understanding, there are two ways a `WM_ERASEBKGND` message could be sent : 1) When I does something like resizing my Window, a `WM_ERASEBKGND` message is sent followed by a `WM_PAINT` message. 2) If I call `InvalidateRect()` with the `bErase` parameter set to `TRUE`, for example: `InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);` This is what happens: A `WM_PAINT` message is sent, and inside the `WM_PAINT` handler `BeginPaint()` is called, now `BeginPaint()` will know that it should send a `WM_ERASEBKGND` message... (to be continued)

Comment: ...So in the first case the Window Procedure will return the value from the `WM_ERASEBKGND` handler to `DispatchMessage()`, while in the second case the Window Procedure will return the value from the `WM_ERASEBKGND` handler to `BeginPaint()`. Is this correct?

Comment: `WM_ERASEBKGND` happens before `WM_PAINT` is sent, because otherwise the system wouldn't know whether it needs to set the `fErase` flag in the `PAINTSTRUCT` or not.

Comment: No I meant the `bErase` parameter in `InvalidateRect()`.

Comment: Another thing just came to my mind: when `WM_ERASEBKGND` is processed, it will validate the area. now when `WM_PAINT` is processed, it shouldn't draw anything, because the area has just been validated. So does this mean that there are two "boolean variables" for the area validation, one for `WM_ERASEBKGND` and the other for `WM_PAINT`?

Comment: I think you're going off on too wide a tangent for the comments. If you have a specific question about some other aspect of the painting cycle please ask another question.